# Is “shall” an appropriate word for a scientific thesis?

Tags: formality, modal-verbs, tech-writing, deontic-vs-epistemic

May I use the word *shall* in my scientific thesis?

As in

> The relevant ones shall be introduced in the following.

Or is *shall* considered slang or outdated?

Comment: Per http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/4722, please ‘never’ use   or ˋbackticksˋ on ELU.
And I don’t know what you think “slang” is, given the question.

Comment: "Slang" in this case should describe anything which is not formal enough to be written in a thesis. Is that enough of an explanation?

Comment: Well, that’s not what *slang* means.

Comment: It's certainly a definition of terms. But no one else uses that definition. Surely the only relevant question here is "Will the people evaluating my thesis consider the use of 'shall' a poor style choice?" And we cannot answer that for you. Don't they have a style guide?

Comment: 'shall' is rare in the US in _any_ register. It sounds outdated.

Comment: @Mitch There you go again with your low-register generalizations! Shall I really spell it out for you as ’twere some RFC? I assure you that if I must, you shall **not** be amused.

Comment: @tchrist: Sure, I'd like to know. If it matters, I'm only talking about AmE. I've heard that BrE tends to use 'shall' more, but I don't have enough familiarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My credentials:  I have read scores upon scores of scientific journal articles, graduate dissertations, and the like.  I have several advanced degrees in science, and have been asked by other scientists to proofread their literature.

My thoughts on the matter:  The word "shall" in a scientific work jumps out as a bit stilted and artificial. It would sound a bit more natural, to my American ears at least, for you to use the word "will" instead of "shall".

All this being said, your use of the word "shall" doesn't jump out at me as being terribly out of place either.  I certainly would not describe it as incorrect.

Answer (score 5):

*Shall* is neither considered slang nor outdated.  From the iPhone application “OED Deluxe”:

**Oxford**

> 1. (in the first person) expressing the future tense: *this time next week I shall be in Scotland | we shan't be gone long.*

And a footnote:

**Usage**

> There is considerable confusion about when to use *shall* and *will*. The traditional rule in standard British English is that *shall* is used with first person pronouns (*I* and *we*) to form the future tense, while *will* is used with second and third persons (*you, he, she, it, they*), e.g. *I shall be late; she will not be there.* When expressing a strong determination to do something the traditional rule is that *will* is used with the first person, and *shall* with the second and third persons, e.g. *I will not tolerate this; you shall go to school.* In practice, however, *shall* and *will* are today used more or less interchangeably in statements (though not in questions). Given that the forms are frequently contracted (*we'll, she'll,* etc.) there is often no need to make a choice between *shall* and *will*, another factor no doubt instrumental in weakening the distinction. In modern English the interchangeable use of *shall* and *will* is an acceptable part of standard British and US English.

Comment: Where is this citation from?

Comment: Oxford, Oxford Dictionary of English, like I wrote.

Comment: You didn’t write. You said *Oxford*, which can mean anything. Do you mean the printed OED?  Do you mean ODO? Do you mean the current OED Online text? Do you have a link?  Please see [our Help Center’s section on “How to reference material written by others”](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: ODEDeluxe iphone app...you tell me...

Comment: Yes sir, anything you say sir.

Comment: It is also worth noting that *shall* tends to refer to obligations, whereas *will*, unsurprisingly, reflects the speaker's will - or desire - to do something.

Comment: I'd never say 'The relevant ones shall be introduced in the following' as I consider it sounds less natural than the alternative with 'will' nowadays. I'd find an authority to support my view, but I'd get in trouble by being late for tea.

Comment: @Anonym: except where it doesn't. In my idiolect, _I shall_ is the ordinary unmarked future, and has no hint of obligation. This is quite common for English people, at least above a certain age - though for many speakers of Scottish English it does not apply.

Comment: @Colin Fine: I'd say _I'll_ is the unmarked form, and _I shall_ is marked as distinctive of a certain group of people.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: yes, even for me, _I shall_ is marked compared with _I'll_, but _I will_ is more marked still.